# How can I get continuous location updates in Android?

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client, fusedlocationproviderapi

The `GoogleApiClient` has been depreceted and now I am having some trouble learning the latest way to get constant location updates. Also, can I get the location updates using `LocationCallback` and `LocationRequetMethod`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am glad that I finally found it. The code is short. I have used `LocationRequest` and `LocationCallback` method. Also, I have used the `fusedLocationProviderClient` for `requestLocationUpdates`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    TextView locationTextView;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationTextView = findViewById(R.id.location_text);

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

//Not the best practices to get runtime permissions, but still here I ask permissions.
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 2);
        }

//Instantiating the Location request and setting the priority and the interval I need to update the location.
        locationRequest = locationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(100);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(50);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

//instantiating the LocationCallBack
        LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult != null) {
                    if (locationResult == null) {
                        return;
                    }
     //Showing the latitude, longitude and accuracy on the home screen.
                    for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                        locationTextView.setText(MessageFormat.format("Lat: {0} Long: {1} Accuracy: {2}", location.getLatitude(),
                                location.getLongitude(), location.getAccuracy()));
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
    }
}
```

In **activity_main.xml**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/location_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/andika"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Also, before all these, I have added this in my **dependencies**

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

And this in my **Manifest**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

[image]

And this keeps on updating in intervals you choose

[image]

Comment: how can we get this location access in the background? I want to store the location on the firebase in the background also how can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

Hi so continious location update is something you should avoid as it drains battery. You can use locationlistner where you could listen to location change. Say you want to update the location and get the attitude and longitude on every 10 meter change.

Sample code to check last,long every 100 meter

```
class LocationService : Service(), LocationListener {
protected var locationManager: LocationManager? = null
var checkGPS = false
var checkNetwork = false

// boolean canGetLocation = false;
var loc: Location? = null

//    double latitude;
//    double longitude;
override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {}
override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}
override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    location
}

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Double.toString(latitude) + longitude + "from method", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
private val location: Location?
    private get() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            )
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
        }
        locationManager = applicationContext
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        checkGPS = locationManager!!
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        checkNetwork = locationManager!!
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
        locationManager!!.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES.toFloat(), this
        )
        if (locationManager != null) {
            val fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
            fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
                if (location != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        java.lang.Double.toString(location.latitude) + location.longitude + "from method",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Double.toString(latitude) + longitude + "from method", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return loc
    }

companion object {
    private const val MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES: Long = 100
    private const val MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES: Long = 30
}
```

}

Comment: how to use it please explain?